# 403 Forbidden : Apache not working after moving document root folder to iCloud drive

Tags: apache, icloud, macos-catalina, icloud-drive

So i'm using MacOS Catalina and my Apache environment was running sweet until i decided to move my document root to the iCloud drive, to keep it backed up.

Before my document root was :

```
/users/admin/www
```

And now it is

```
/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www
```

I edited httpd.conf accordingly :

```
DocumentRoot "/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www"
<Directory "/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www/myfolder">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restarted Apache, restarted the machine but now i can access 127.0.0.1, EXCEPT one specific folder (let's call it www/myfolder). When i try to access 127.0.0.1/myfolder, i get the error below :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Checking the apache log file, this is the error i'm getting :

```
[Thu Oct 24 14:00:24.830700 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 61703] [client 127.0.0.1:57804] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/www/myfolder/public_html/
```

What am i missing here ? Please help, i need to work :D

Comment: Did you check the permissions, ownership, and group for www and its parent directories? All should be accessible to apache user and its group

Comment: @niklaz Thanks for replying, the www fodler is set do everyone. Does the /users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs needs too ?

Comment: @niklaz I just added new info, please help :D

Comment: you need to set directory permissions on *all* of the parent directories to allow access by the apache user/group: `/users`, `/users/admin`, `/users/admin/Library`, `/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents` and `/users/admin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`, in addition to `www`

Comment: @Z4-tier Do i need to put anything more on httpd.conf ?

Comment: @delphirules I added an update to my answer with 2 more detailed suggestions about what I think the problem might be. Based on what information I have, I'm relatively sure that it's related to `access_compat` and the way you are mixing different versions of the apache configuration syntax.

Comment: I think you are having the same problem as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392347/385685) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/335265/385685). I'm using ACLs to get around the permission problem on folders in iCloud Drive, see [my answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398798/385685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I am seeing is that you are using Apache 2.4 style syntax in your directory block, but then in your error log the module throwing the error is
`access_compat`. Per the Apache documentation:

> *The directives provided by mod_access_compat have been deprecated* by mod_authz_host. Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like Require is technically possible but discouraged. This module was created to support configurations containing only old directives to facilitate the 2.4 upgrade

Next clue is the error code: `AH01797`. This is caused by a [server configuration issue](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration):

> **Client denied by server configuration**
>
> This error means that the access to the directory on the file system was denied by an Apache configuration.

I am assuming here that you are actually using 2.4, and that `access_compat` is enabled by mistake.

Take a look through your configuration files again, and find the `LoadModule` directive that is loading `mod_access_compat`, and comment it out. It might be in your `httpd.conf` file, but there are numerous different styles of organizing and configuring an Apache install, so it could be elsewhere. If you have a Debian-style install, you need to remove the symbolic link `/etc/apache2/mods_enabled/mod_access_compat`. `Grep -R access_compat *` might help.

**EDIT** 2 more observations:

1. In the second `directory` stanza, you have

```
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

Which is mixing old directive syntax with new, and is also redundant. Disable `access_compat` again, and also remove that `Allow from all` line before restarting Apache.

2. I don't think the second `directory` stanza is even necessary. You could probably delete the whole block and restart the server, and it would work.

First try (1) by disabling `access_compat` and removing that `Allow` directive from your `httpd.conf` file, and restart apache using `apache2ctl -k graceful`. If that doesn't work, comment out the entire second `directory` stanza and restart again.

I am about 50% sure this will fix it. If it doesn't then I will really need to see your entire httpd.conf file before I can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thanks for answering, did this (comment the mod_access_compat), but now all i get is this error : 'This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.'... maybe i need to reboot ?

Comment: Well i un-commented and it goes back to normal, but i can't access only a specific subfolder of www...

Comment: @delphirules one of your config files might contain directives with syntax requiring `access_compat`. Without knowning what version of Apache you're on or the contents of the config files, its had to say for sure if that module is involved. I left another comment on the original post, but I'm not sure that directory permissions are the (only) source of the problem here. `AH01797` is specifically documented as being caused by the Apache server configuration. There is likely some other section of `httpd.conf` or another config file that has directives that are blocking access to that location.

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 29 2019 19:01:57

Comment: You see, now i can access all folder in www, EXCEPT one folder gives me the Forbidden error... What could it be ?

Comment: You mean that other subdirectories of the new `www` folder are being served by Apache, and you can access them through a browser, but just one specific subdirectory of `www` is giving an HTTP 403 error? So `/path/to/www/foo` is working, but `/path/to/www/baz` gives an error? If that is correct, first check the owner/group settings and permissions on the folder and it's contents to make sure it matches one of the working folders. If that looks ok, you might try adding another `<Directory>` block to `http.conf` for the new directory, but otherwise the same as the one in the original post.

Comment: if you update `http.conf` also remember to bounce the server: `apache2ctl -k graceful`. Also, double check that you don't have any `.htaccess` files sitting around under `www`..

Comment: That's correct, the www folder works ok, and all its subfolder also works ok EXCEPT one specific folder. I just updated the question with up to date settings and the currint issue, can you please check ? I've been stuck in this issue for 3 days now :/

Comment: just out of curiosity, was it `Edit: #1` or `Edit: #2` that did it?

Comment: To be honest, i don't even know anymore.... I did so much things that i'm not sure what really fix the issue. But sure disabling access_compat did something